# jQuery filter select options

Tags: jquery, html-select

Is it possible to filter specific select options?

I have a code :

```
<select id="adcategory" name="adcategory">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="25" class="dropdownparentcategory">Florida Atlantic University</option>

    <option value="26">- Books </option>
    <option value="27">- Electronics</option>
    <option value="28">- For Rent</option>

    <option value="17" class="dropdownparentcategory">Florida International University</option>

    <option value="18">- Books</option>
    <option value="19">- Electronics</option>
    <option value="20">- For Rent</option>

    <option value="1" class="dropdownparentcategory">Florida Tech</option>
    <option value="2">- Books</option>
    <option value="3">- Electronics</option>
    <option value="7">- For Rent</option>


</select>
```

So if the variable for example `$school = Florida Atlantic University` than show only thoes options witch is till next school category ( `.dropdownparentcategory` ), so in this case they would be only :

```
<select id="adcategory" name="adcategory">
    <option value="">Select</option>

    <option value="26">- Books </option>
    <option value="27">- Electronics</option>
    <option value="28">- For Rent</option>

</select>
```

As you can see in this image :

[image]

Is it possible to create with jQuery?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like potentially bad design. I would suggest moving to [`<optgroup>` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/optgroup) tags to group your drop down items:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Florida Atlantic University">
        <option value="1">Text</option>
        <option value="2">Text</option>
        <option value="3">Text</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Florida Tech">
        <option value="4">Text</option>
        <option value="5">Text</option>
        <option value="6">Text</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Then it's trivially easy to select child elements;

```
$('optgroup[label*="' + yourSchoolName + '"]').find('option')
```

Comment: As much as I'm proud of my answer, I must say this is how it should be done.

Comment: Looks great, but can I change option fields with class .dropdownparentcategory to optgroup straight with jQuery? Because this code is populated by one plugin so I think it will be hard to find where it is generating this content

Comment: You can do replacements of tags, however it might be more work than you want. `$('.dropdownparentcategory').replaceWith('<optgroup/>')` would work, and then move the child elements up into the optgroup. However, it's probably easier to change the place generating the html.

Answer (score 2):

Sure is.

```
$("#adcategory option:contains('Florida International University')").nextUntil(".dropdownparentcategory")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xeon06/YEeMH/

Answer (score 2):

i would say, add classes for all your  element by categorizing

```
<option class="js_atl" value="25" />
<option class="js_atl" value="26" />
<option class="js_atl" value="27" />
<option class="js_int" value="28" />
<option class="js_int" value="29" />
```

so like that you can use ur $school = "Florida Atlantic University"
show or append or what ever with `$(".js_atl")` for the other category `$(".js_int")` which returns array of selected elements in that class category.

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to apply a style of "display: none;" to the tags you don't want visible.