# problems hiding option elements using jQuery in all browsers except Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari

I have some content being loaded asynchronously on a server that runs jQuery 1.3.2

I am trying to hide options in a second select based on values in the first select. I've been able to reproduce my problem with this example below.

The example works fine in Firefox. In Chrome, choosing B in the first select will cause the second select's pull down options to go blank. In IE, no option hiding occurs at all. In Safari, the second select will choose the first option in what should be the visible options, but options that should be hidden are still visible.

Is this a problem in my jQuery code?

This a Jira gadget for anyone familiar. That is why I use `.live("change", function())` instead of `.change()`.

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div class="gadget">
         <form action="localhost/promotedByTable/go">
            <select id="projectId" name="projectId">
               <option value="p-10100">A</option>
               <option value="p-10200">B</option>
               <option value="p-10300">C</option>
            </select>
            <select id="fixVersion" name="fixVersion">
               <option value="10100-10400">1</option>
               <option value="10100-10401">2</option>
               <option value="10100-10402">3</option>
               <option value="10100-10403">4</option>
               <option value="10100-10404">5</option>
               <option value="10100-10405">6</option>
               <option value="10100-10406">7</option>
               <option value="10100-10407">8</option>
               <option value="10100-10408">9</option>
               <option value="10100-10409">10</option>
               <option value="10100-10410">11</option>
               <option value="10100-10411">12</option>
               <option value="10100-10412">13</option>
               <option value="10100-10413">14</option>
               <option value="10100-10414">15</option>
               <option value="10100-10415">16</option>
               <option value="10100-10416">17</option>
               <option value="10100-10417">18</option>
               <option value="10100-10418">19</option>
               <option value="10100-10419">20</option>
               <option value="10100-10420">21</option>
               <option value="10100-10421">22</option>
               <option value="10100-10422">23</option>
               <option value="10100-10423">24</option>
               <option value="10100-10424">25</option>
               <option value="10100-10425">26</option>
               <option value="10100-10426">27</option>
               <option value="10100-10427">28</option>
               <option value="10100-10428">29</option>
               <option value="10100-10429">30</option>
               <option value="10100-10430">31</option>
               <option value="10100-10431">32</option>
               <option value="10100-10432">33</option>
               <option value="10100-10433">34</option>
               <option value="10100-10434">35</option>
               <option value="10100-10435">36</option>
               <option value="10100-10436">37</option>
               <option value="10100-10437">38</option>
               <option value="10100-10438">39</option>
               <option value="10100-10439">40</option>
               <option value="10100-10440">41</option>
               <option value="10100-10441">42</option>
               <option value="10100-10442">43</option>
               <option value="10100-10443">44</option>
               <option value="10200-10500">1.0</option>
               <option value="10200-10501">1.1</option>
               <option value="10200-10502">1.2</option>
               <option value="10200-10503">1.3</option>
               <option value="10200-10504">1.4</option>
               <option value="10200-10505">1.5</option>
               <option value="10200-10506">1.6</option>
               <option value="10200-10507">1.7</option>
               <option value="10200-10508">1.8</option>
               <option value="10200-10509">1.9</option>
               <option value="10200-10510">1.10</option>
               <option value="10200-10511">1.11</option>
               <option value="10200-10512">1.12</option>
               <option value="10200-10513">1.13</option>
               <option value="10200-10514">1.14</option>
               <option value="10200-10515">1.15</option>
               <option value="10200-10516">1.16</option>
               <option value="10200-10517">1.17</option>
               <option value="10200-10518">1.18</option>
               <option value="10200-10519">1.19</option>
               <option value="10200-10520">1.20</option>
               <option value="10200-10521">1.21</option>
               <option value="10200-10522">1.22</option>
               <option value="10200-10523">1.23</option>
               <option value="10200-10524">1.24</option>
               <option value="10200-10525">1.25</option>
               <option value="10200-10526">1.26</option>
               <option value="10200-10527">1.27</option>
               <option value="10200-10528">1.28</option>
               <option value="10200-10529">1.29</option>
               <option value="10200-10530">1.30</option>
               <option value="10200-10531">1.31</option>
               <option value="10200-10532">1.32</option>
               <option value="10200-10533">1.33</option>
               <option value="10200-10534">1.34</option>
               <option value="10200-10535">1.35</option>
               <option value="10200-10536">1.36</option>
               <option value="10200-10537">1.37</option>
               <option value="10200-10538">1.38</option>
               <option value="10200-10539">1.39</option>
               <option value="10200-10540">1.40</option>
               <option value="10200-10541">1.41</option>
               <option value="10300-10600">3.1</option>
               <option value="10300-10601">3.4</option>
               <option value="10300-10602">3.7</option>
               <option value="10300-10603">4</option>
               <option value="10300-10604">4.3</option>
               <option value="10300-10605">4.6</option>
               <option value="10300-10606">4.9</option>
               <option value="10300-10607">5.2</option>
               <option value="10300-10608">5.5</option>
               <option value="10300-10609">5.8</option>
               <option value="10300-10610">6.1</option>
               <option value="10300-10611">6.4</option>
               <option value="10300-10612">6.7</option>
               <option value="10300-10613">7</option>
               <option value="10300-10614">7.3</option>
               <option value="10300-10615">7.6</option>
               <option value="10300-10616">7.9</option>
               <option value="10300-10617">8.2</option>
               <option value="10300-10618">8.5</option>
               <option value="10300-10619">8.8</option>
               <option value="10300-10620">9.1</option>
               <option value="10300-10621">9.4</option>
               <option value="10300-10622">9.7</option>
               <option value="10300-10623">10</option>
               <option value="10300-10624">10.3</option>
               <option value="10300-10625">10.6</option>
               <option value="10300-10626">10.9</option>
               <option value="10300-10627">11.2</option>
               <option value="10300-10628">11.5</option>
               <option value="10300-10629">11.8</option>
            </select>
         </form>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         jQuery(function() {
            jQuery("form[action*='/promotedByTable/'] #projectId").live("change", function() {
               var projSelect = jQuery(this);
               var fixVersion = projSelect.closest("div.gadget").find("#fixVersion");
               var firstVisible;
               fixVersion.find("option").each(function() {
                  var option = jQuery(this);
                  var show = option.attr("value").split("-")[0] == projSelect.val().split("-")[1];
                  option.toggle(show);
                  if(show && !firstVisible) {
                     firstVisible = option;
                  }
               });
               var none = fixVersion.find("option#no-versions");
               if(firstVisible) {
                  none.remove();
                  fixVersion.val(firstVisible.attr("value"));
               }
               else if(none.length) {
                  none.show();
                  fixVersion.append(none).val(none.text());
               }
               else {
                  none = jQuery("<option id='no-versions'>(Select a project with versions)</option>");
                  fixVersion.append(none).val(none.text());
               }
            });
         });
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/97UVJ/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems.

1. `live()` [doesn't work](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_thread/thread/e74de6015020d160?pli=1) with jQuery 1.3.2 and Internet Explorer.
2. `display: none` doesn't work on option elements if the first 20 or so options are all going to be hidden.

I ended up with this, which still doesn't work in IE unless I use `.change()` instead of `.live('change')`

```
jQuery(function() {
   jQuery("form[action*='/promotedByTable/'] #projectId").live("change", function() {
      var projSelect = jQuery(this);
      var pid = projSelect.val().split("-")[1];
      var gadget = projSelect.closest("div.gadget");
      var fixVersion = gadget.find("#fixVersion");
      var hiddenVersions = gadget.find("#hiddenVersions");
      if(!hiddenVersions.length) {
         hiddenVersions = jQuery("<select id='hiddenVersions' style='display:none;' />").insertAfter(fixVersion);
      }
          // hiding options doesn't seem to work except in firefox
      // instead let's move them to a hidden select
      fixVersion.find("option").each(function() {
         hiddenVersions.append(this);
      });
      var firstVisible;
      hiddenVersions.find("option").each(function() {
         var option = jQuery(this);
         if(pid == option.attr("value").split("-")[0]) {
            fixVersion.append(option);
            if(!firstVisible) {
               firstVisible = option;
            }
         }
      });
      var none = fixVersion.find("option#no-versions");
      if(firstVisible) {
         none.remove();
      }
      else if(none.length) {
         fixVersion.append(none).val(none.text());
      }
      else {
         none = jQuery("<option id='no-versions'>(Select a project with versions)</option>");
         fixVersion.append(none).val(none.text());
      }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just recently discovered to my chagrin that the option tag does not support the display: none style attribute on most modern browsers.  I'd recommend checking out this and see if it can't lead you in a different direction.

[jQuery filter select options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068331/jquery-filter-select-options/7068422#7068422)