# How to change a seleclist options from another selectlist?

Tags: jquery, selectlist, optgroup

I have two seleclists. I want to filter second selectlist options from first select list.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#sehir').change(function() {
        var sehir = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
        var options = $('#ilce').filter('[label=' + sehir + ']');
        $('#ilce').html(options);
    });
});
```

And first selectlist:

```
<select name="sehirid" id="sehir" class="form-control">
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Second selectlist:

```
<select name="ilceid" id="ilce" class="form-control">
    <optgroup label="Option 1">
        <option parent="Option 1" value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option parent="Option 1" value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option parent="Option 1" value="3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Option 2">
        <option parent="Option 2" value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option parent="Option 2" value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option parent="Option 2" value="3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Option 3">
        <option parent="Option 3" value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option parent="Option 3" value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option parent="Option 3" value="3">Option 3</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

But this code is not working. What's wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068331/jquery-filter-select-options

Answer (score 1):

Two issues; firstly `filter()` should be `find()` as you're searching for child elements of the `#ilce` element. Secondly, you need to wrap the value in the attribute selector in quotes. Try this:

```
$('#sehir').change(function() {
    var sehir = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    var options = $('#ilce').find('optgroup[label="' + sehir + '"]');
    $('#ilce').html(options);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pg7xjyt/)

Note that this will only work *once*, as you remove the other options groups after the first selection. If you want to be able to change the selection, you can just disable the other `optgroup` elements, like this:

```
$('#sehir').change(function() {
    var sehir = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    var optgroup = $('#ilce').find('optgroup[label="' + sehir + '"]');
    $('#ilce').find('optgroup').prop('disabled', false).not(optgroup).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4pg7xjyt/1/)

Comment: Thanks for help. But i want to ask one question again. How to remove unselected optgroup under second selectlist?

Comment: The first example does this.

Comment: first example, as u say only work once, your second example, just disable unselected options. but i want to remove unselected options as your second example.

Answer (score 0):

You want to find all options under the particular group. This can be achieved as below:

```
var options = $('optgroup[label="' + sehir + '"]').find('option');
```